# C++ how to make a function that has optional parameters

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I want to make a function that has parameters like here
`void example(int x, int y, int z);`
but I dont have to put `z` in there like this `example(34, 21);` is that possible in C++?

Comment: And when this `z` is not there, what do you expect all the code in the function, that references `z`, to do?

Comment: write two functions of the same name or provide a default value for z

Comment: they are called [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)

Comment: TLDR: `void example(int x, int y, int z=0){}`

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two options

1. Create a overloaded function that takes 2 parameters. So you would have

```cpp
void example(int x, int y, int z)
```

and

```cpp
void example(int x, int y)
```

2. Assign default value to z

```cpp
void example(int x, int y, int z = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to use undefined amount of parameters is to use **ellipsis**. For further read i recomend to look through
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments
To implement it just google **how to use c++ ellipsis** and thats it!

Comment: this is C feature considered harmful.

Comment: @MarekR anyway it is used in many STD C/C++ functions

Comment: Only in C API like `printf`. In real C++ API you do not have it. C++20 introduced `std::format` which uses variadic templates to ensure it is type safe and fast.

Comment: Anyway if you really think this is a good idea, try to use it with such simple case like this question. You will see how many problems it introduces.